# why does fail2ban not match script not found

Tags: regex, fail2ban

Why does the following `fail2ban regex`

```
failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s ((AH001(28|30): )?File does not exist|(AH01264: )?script not found or unable to stat).*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s script '.*' not found or unable to stat
```

not match

```
[client 111.111.111.111:51008] script '/srv/www/htdocs/wwwuni/fileadmin/Dokumente/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: The failregex are two lines; the second line begins after stat),$

Comment: maybe are you missing the $ after `stat` on the second line?

Comment: the missing $ was not the problem. The problem was the definition of _apache_error_client which didn't match the line

I changed 
_apache_error_client = \[[^]]*\] \[(error|\S+:\S+)\]( \[pid \d+])? \[client <HOST>(:\d{1,5})?\] 
to
_apache_error_client = \[[^]]*\] \[(:error|\S+:\S+)\]( \[pid \d+])? \[client <HOST>(:\d{1,5})?\]
(: in front of error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved after changing the definition of
_apache_error_client in apache-common.conf
to _apache_error_client = [[^]]*] [(:error|\S+:\S+)]( [pid \d+])? [client (:\d{1,5})?]